# I am trying to filter images by specific likes which I have entered by I am not able to figure it how

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to filter images by specific likes which I have entered by I am not able to figure it how.

I have 2 main classes and first one is InputSlider as below:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";
import MuiInput from "@mui/material/Input";
import ThumbDownIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbDown";
import ThumbUpIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUp";

const Input = styled(MuiInput)`
  width: 42px;
`;

const InputSlider = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(500);

  const handleSliderChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value === "" ? "" : Number(event.target.value));
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    if (value < 0) {
      setValue(0);
    } else if (value > 500) {
      setValue(500);
    }
  };
  let likeCountByFilter = { value };
  console.log(likeCountByFilter);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 800 }}>
      <Typography id="input-slider" textAlign={"center"}>
        Likes
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
        <Grid item>
          <ThumbDownIcon />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider
            value={typeof value === "number" ? value : 0}
            onChange={handleSliderChange}
            aria-labelledby="input-slider"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <ThumbUpIcon />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Input
            value={value}
            size="small"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            inputProps={{
              step: 1,
              min: 0,
              max: 10000,
              type: "number",
              "aria-labelledby": "input-slider",
            }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default InputSlider;
```

and Second one is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ImageList from "@mui/material/ImageList";
import ImageListItem from "@mui/material/ImageListItem";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/icons-material/CheckBox";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder";
import Favorite from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import FavoriteBorder from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import InputSlider from "./InputSlider";
import { itemData } from "./itemData";

const NewImageCorouse = ({ photos }) => {
  return (
    <ImageList cols={3}>
      {photos.map((item) => (
        <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
          <img
            src={`${item.img}?w=164&h=164&fit=crop&auto=format`}
            srcSet={`${item.img}?w=164&h=164&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
            alt={item.title}
            loading="lazy"
          />
          <div style={{}}>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <FavoriteBorder icon={<FavoriteBorder />} name="checkedH" />
              }
              label={`${item.likeCount} Likes`}
            />
          </div>
        </ImageListItem>
      ))}
    </ImageList>
  );
};

export default NewImageCorouse;
```

I have data in itemData.js and there I have `likeCount` for each object.
I am trying to solve how I can only show the photos when I try to input like count in Slider it will show only photos which have likes only more than input amount.

```
export const itemData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551963831-b3b1ca40c98e",
    title: "Breakfast",
    likeCount: 10,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551782450-a2132b4ba21d",
    title: "Burger",
    likeCount: 15,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522770179533-24471fcdba45",
    title: "Camera",
    likeCount: 28,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444418776041-9c7e33cc5a9c",
    title: "Coffee",
    likeCount: 187,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533827432537-70133748f5c8",
    title: "Hats",
    likeCount: 74,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558642452-9d2a7deb7f62",
    title: "Honey",
    likeCount: 898,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516802273409-68526ee1bdd6",
    title: "Basketball",
    likeCount: 127,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518756131217-31eb79b20e8f",
    title: "Fern",
    likeCount: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597645587822-e99fa5d45d25",
    title: "Mushrooms",
    likeCount: 54,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567306301408-9b74779a11af",
    title: "Tomato basil",
    likeCount: 14,
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471357674240-e1a485acb3e1",
    title: "Sea star",
    likeCount: 28,
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589118949245-7d38baf380d6",
    title: "Bike",
    likeCount: 247,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to pass back out the slider value, and then filter the `photos` array prop that is passed to `NewImageCorouse`.

1. Use an `useEffect` hook to call an `onChange` handler for the `InputSlider`.

   ```
   const InputSlider = ({ onChange = () => {} }) => {
     const [value, setValue] = React.useState(500);

     React.useEffect(() => {
       onChange(value);
     }, [onChange, value]);

     const handleSliderChange = (event, newValue) => {
       setValue(newValue);
     };

     const handleInputChange = (event) => {
       setValue(event.target.value === "" ? "" : Number(event.target.value));
     };

     const handleBlur = () => {
       if (value < 0) {
         setValue(0);
       } else if (value > 500) {
         setValue(500);
       }
     };

     return (
       <Box sx={{ width: 800 }}>
         <Typography id="input-slider" textAlign={"center"}>
           Likes
         </Typography>
         <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
           <Grid item>
             <ThumbDownIcon />
           </Grid>
           <Grid item xs>
             <Slider
               min={0}
               max={1000}
               step={1}
               value={typeof value === "number" ? value : 0}
               onChange={handleSliderChange}
               aria-labelledby="input-slider"
             />
           </Grid>
           <Grid item>
             <ThumbUpIcon />
           </Grid>
           <Grid item>
             <Input
               value={value}
               size="small"
               onChange={handleInputChange}
               onBlur={handleBlur}
               inputProps={{
                 step: 1,
                 min: 0,
                 max: 1000,
                 type: "number",
                 "aria-labelledby": "input-slider"
               }}
             />
           </Grid>
         </Grid>
       </Box>
     );
   };
   ```
2. Filter the `itemData` array that is passed as `photos` prop by the saved "likes" value.

   ```
   function App() {
     const [likes, setLikes] = React.useState(0);

     return (
       <div>
         <InputSlider onChange={setLikes} />

         <NewImageCorouse
           photos={itemData.filter(({ likeCount }) => likeCount > likes)}
         />
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

[image: Edit i-am-trying-to-filter-images-by-specific-likes-which-i-have-entered-by-i-am-not]

[image]